# Why does changing an element through jQuery affect my media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a Navigation bar that on mobile is transparent until you scroll past a certain point, but it switches back and forth through the use of a JavaScript function I'm using for the window scroll listener. But once that function changes the navigation properly, I find that my media query to show the navigation bar again on a desktop width does not change, but only when my JS has ran for the mobile width. I wanna believe it's how I'm using classes and IDs, but I've tried all the different ways and the media query still doesn't work properly.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    
    /* Change navbar for desktop */
    .navigation-bar {
        background: black;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .navigation-bar .logo {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

The above is my desktop media query for the navigation

```
/**
 * Show navigation bar on mobile
 * after 400 pixels scrolled
 */
function showNavOnMobile() {
    if(window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
            $(".navigation-bar").css("background", "black");
            $(".navigation-bar .logo").css("display", "inline");
        }
        else {
            $(".navigation-bar").css("background", "none");
            $(".navigation-bar .logo").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}
```

Only when that function runs, the media query doesn't work, but if I was to not scroll the page, the media query would work just as I need it to.

*This is my first post, so I apologize if it's not exactly the way you should format it.*

Comment: `.css()` changes the style attribute of the element which has greater specificity than your media query. I would recommend adding a class with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead.

Comment: I would suggest using either media queries to control the `display` property, or JavaScript, not both. Use `opacity` to control the appearance in JavaScript.